# Stop div from wrapping around content?

Tags: html, css

This question is probebly asked a hundred times already so I appologise for asking it again. The other questions simply didn't help in getting my problem solved. Been trying for like 2 hours now so I'm a bit frustrated and realy need some help.

I've got a section with 2 divs inside. I'm trying to get the left div to be 100% - 200px and the right div in whatever is left over. But no matter what I try the divs keep on wrapping around their content.

I've put up a jsfiddle to keep this question a bit short:

http://jsfiddle.net/nttzV/1/

This is the css part that's needed:

```
section {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 2px solid green;
}
.box1 {
float: left;
width: calc(100% -200px);
border: 2px solid red;
display: block;
}
.box2 {
float: left;
margin-left: 5px;
width: 180px;
border: 2px solid blue;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'm up-voting this for the sheer fact that I've been wanting to do this in CSS for forever and could never find how.  I've always tried, but without the `calc()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a space after the minus in `calc`:

```
width: calc(100% - 200px);
```

Comment: Seriously.. I feel like the worst possible idiot in the history of mankind now. Thanks a lot! You're my hero for today! xD

Answer (score 0):

You want "left div to be 100% - 200px and the right div whatever is left over". The left-over area will always be 200px.

Instead, try making the right `<div>` 200px and the left `<div>` whatever is left over. Then you don't need to use `calc()`, whose [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/calc) is somewhat limited.

Something like this:

```
<section>
    <div class="boxR"></div>
    <div class="boxL"></div>
</section>
```

```
section {
    min-width:300px;
}

div.boxR,
div.boxL {
    min-height:200px;
}

div.boxR {
    float:right;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

div.boxL {
    margin-right:200px;
    background-color:#555;
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5d2bb/)